# How to get the client IP address in a JAX-RS resource class without injecting the HttpServletRequest?

Tags: jakarta-ee, jax-rs, java-ee-6

We are using JAX-RS 1.0 and I want to get the client IP address in my resource class. Currently I inject the `HttpServletRequest` as a method parameter and then get the IP address.

I want to make my code cleaner. I am thinking if I can use a `MessageBodyReader` class and set the IP address. But if I use a `MessageBodyReader` I have to unmarshall the XML to a Java object which is additional logic as far as I believe.

Can anyone please let me know how to get the client IP address without having to inject the `HttpServletRequest`.

Comment: What's the problem in injecting the `HttpServletRequest`? Have you considered injecting it as a field of your resource class?

Comment: You can use `http://checkip.amazonaws.com`

Comment: @DibakarPaul It will return your own IP instead of the client IP.

Comment: @Cassio We have many web services and every time a developer adds a new web service, injecting the servlet request as a method parameter or as an instance field is inevitable. So I was thinking if this can be made easier and the code looks cleaner or better.

Comment: Are you using CDI?

Comment: No I am not using CDI. But I can use if it is possible through CDI

Comment: With CDI, you will need to inject a bean with the IP in your resource classes. You also can encapsulate the `HttpServletRequest` in a bean. If it's alright, I can write an answer for you.

Comment: The JAX stuff is a thin layer on top of servlets - it is slightly easier but it's really just a servlet.  As @CássioMazzochiMolin says, there is no magic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*There's no magic.* What you can do is wrap the [`HttpServletRequest`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html) into a CDI bean with request scope ([`@RequestScoped`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/enterprise/context/RequestScoped.html)) and then inject this bean into your JAX-RS resource classes:

```java
import javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

@RequestScoped
public class RequestDetails {

    @Inject
    private HttpServletRequest request;

    public String getRemoteAddress() {
        return request.getRemoteAddr();
    }
}
```

```java
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

@Stateless
@Path("client-address")
public class ClientAddressResource {

    @Inject
    private RequestDetails requestDetails; 

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public Response getClientRemoteAddress() {
        return Response.ok(requestDetails.getRemoteAddress()).build();
    }
}
```

I know this approach is not much different from injecting the [`HttpServletRequest`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html). *But there's no magic.*

Comment: Thanks Cassio. Meanwhile I created an abstract class and injected the request into that using @Context and added a protected method to get the ip address. I did not test it yet but hopes it works as expected