# retrieving client IP address in quarkus

Tags: jax-rs, quarkus

Just as the title says, I need a help to get the local IP of the client in a quarkus resource  ¿any idea?

I already try this but it dosen't work

```
import javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.ws.rs.DELETE;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ResourceContext;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response.Status;


@Path("/auth")
@RequestScoped
public class AuthResource {
    
        @GET
    @Path("/getIpAddres")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String getIpAddres(@Context HttpServletRequest request){
       String ip = request.getRemoteAddr();
       return ip;
    }
```

Comment: Can you explain what "it doesn't work" mean?

Comment: This answer may help :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38243446/how-to-get-the-client-ip-address-in-a-jax-rs-resource-class-without-injecting-th/38247747

Answer (score 2):

Pretty simple. Instead of using `@Context HttpServletRequest request`. do this instead:

```
@Path("/auth")
@RequestScoped
public class AuthResource {

    @Inject
    RoutingContext context;
    
    @GET
    @Path("/getIpAddres")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String getIpAddres(){
       String ip = context.request().host();
       return ip;
    }
```

I faced this problem myself. Cool thing about this `RoutingContext` is that this class can be injected into the Service layer, and it will have all the context of the ip, and other stuff, given that the Service was called by the Controller.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Just call the method **remoteAddress()**

```
    @Path("/getIpAddres")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String getIpAddres(@Context HttpServletRequest request){
       String ip = request.remoteAddress().hostAddress();
       return ip;
    }
```

`